# ¿Como poder usar un atributo del modelo User que trae por defecto Django?

Tags: python, django

Lo que quiero hacer es, poder usar el primer nombre del usuario que esta registrado en la base de datos usando el modelo User que trae por defecto django, mi idea en si es poder usar su nombre como una especie de selector con un foreign key , para que al guardar mi documento haga referencia a ese usuario que seleciono, aqui esta mi codigo del modelo

## models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class analisis_doc(models.Model):
  nombre_doc = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  referencia=models.CharField(max_length=200)   
  area = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
```

## forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import analisis_doc

class analisis_form(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model=cargo
    fields=[
     'nombre_doc',
     'referencia',
     'area',
     'user',
    ]

    labels={
     'nombre_doc':('Nombre del documento'),
     'referencia':('Referencias'),
     'area':('Area'),
     'user':('Seleccione nomrbre del usuario'),
    }

    widgets={
     'nombre_doc':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form=control'}),
     'referencia':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form=control'}),
     'area':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form=control'}),
     'user':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form=control'}),
    }
```

Esta es mi diea que tengo de como podria usar el nombre de la tabla User q tiene django pero creo q esta mal , si alguien pudiera , por favor diganme , en donde me equivoco o como es que deberia hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

De esta forma quedaría tu formulario

```
from app.models import User

class analisis_form(forms.Form):

    nombre_doc=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        }),
           error_messages={'required': 'Proporciona nombre del documento.'})

    referencia = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        }),
           error_messages={'required': 'Proporciona referencia'})


    area = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        }),
           error_messages={'required': 'Proporciona area.'})

    usuario = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class':"form-control",}),
                              required=True,
                              error_messages={
                              'required':'Seleccione usuario'
                              },
                              queryset=queryset=User.objects.all()
```

Queryset consulta sobre el modelo user y trae todos los usuarios dados de alta previamente, para mostrarlos en una lista desplegable

```
queryset=queryset=User.objects.all()
```

Comment: OOOOOH waoooooo gracias , mil gracias entendi muy bien lo que me explicaste gracias enserio, aaah y la parte del modelo que puse asi, esta bien llamarlo de esta manera?       user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)

Comment: Es correcto excepto por default=1, si no estoy mal default=1 va a hacer que el campo "USER" siempre sea el usuario con id=1

 Por ejemplo si en tu modelo existiera un campo "status", y deseas que este campo se autocomplete cada vez que se ingresa un nuevo registro
 entonces pondrias: status=models.IntegerField(default=1); 
 Por consigueinte tu campo "USER" siempre se va autocompletar con 1, si lo que
 quieres es autocompletar el campo user siempre con el ID=1 entonces es correcto, pero si quieres seleccionarlo con una lista desplegable
 entonces no debes poner default.

Comment: @Lun si la respuesta te fue de mucha ayuda y resolvió tu pregunta, no olvides aceptar la respuesta para cerrar así esta pregunta

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la aclaracion a @NetzaL gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Usar Esto Amigo

```
#en setting.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<appname>.NameModelClass'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'seguridad.User'
```

```
#en seguridad/models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad, verbose_name='Ciudad', on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
    cedula = models.CharField(verbose_name='Cédula',max_length=10,blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(verbose_name='Dirección',max_length=120,blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha Nacimiento',blank=True, null=True)
    telefono = models.CharField(verbose_name='Telefono',max_length=88,blank=True, null=True)
    genero = models.CharField(verbose_name='Genero',choices=tipo_genero,default='N',max_length=1,blank=True, null=True)
    estado_civil = models.CharField(verbose_name='Estado Civil',choices=tipo_estado_civil,default='S',max_length=1,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

De esta forma puedes agregar los atributos que viene en django